# RemoveDuplicates Method

Tags: excel, vba, openedge, progress-4gl

Has anyone used Excel's RemoveDuplicates method in Progress 4GL? Could you tell me what the syntax is?

Example in VBA:

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=xlYes
```

Here is what I have tried in Progress 4gl:

```
PROCEDURE pi-elimina-duplicata:

  DEFINE VARIABLE v-chr-excel-application AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO. 
  DEFINE VARIABLE v-chr-work-book AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE v-chr-work-sheet AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE v-chr-range AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE v-int-line AS INTEGER NO-UNDO INITIAL 1.
  DEFINE VARIABLE v-int-ultimalinha AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE VARIABLE v-coluna-a AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(20)".
  DEFINE VARIABLE v-coluna-b AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(20)".
  DEFINE VARIABLE v-coluna-c AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(20)".

  CREATE 'excel.application':U v-chr-excel-application. 
  v-chr-excel-application:VISIBLE = TRUE.
  ASSIGN
    v-chr-work-book = v-chr-excel-application:Workbooks:OPEN(c-nome-arquivo) v-chr-work-sheet = v-chr-excel-application:Sheets:ITEM(1)
    v-int-ultimalinha = v-chr-excel-application:Activesheet:Usedrange:Rows:COUNT
  .

  /* v-chr-work-sheet:Range("$A$1:$AC$568"):RemoveDuplicates:COLUMNS:Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, , 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29):HEADER:xlYes. */

  v-chr-work-sheet:UsedRange:RemoveDuplicates("A:AC",1) /* ("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, , 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29", YES) */. 

  /* Range(“A1:C8”).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes */

  v-chr-excel-application:Workbooks:APPLICATION:QUIT.

  RELEASE OBJECT v-chr-excel-application NO-ERROR.
  RELEASE OBJECT v-chr-work-sheet NO-ERROR.
  RELEASE OBJECT v-chr-work-book NO-ERROR.

END PROCEDURE.
```

Comment: Are you using the COM Interface (Active X) or .NET Interop to use Excel from the Progress 4GL?

Comment: No, I'm manipulating an Excel spreadsheet, with some VBA commands, through a script written in Progress 4GL, but I can't implement this method of removing duplicates, because I don't know the correct syntax for it.

Comment: Sorry - it's important to know, if your Progress 4GL "scripts" (we usully call it procedures) use the COM intrfrace or .NET. I suggest you share some existing source code to clarify.

Comment: PROCEDURE pi-elimina-duplicata:
   DEFINE VARIABLE v-chr-excel-application AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO.
   DEFINE VARIABLE v-chr-work-book         AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO.
   DEFINE VARIABLE v-chr-work-sheet        AS COM-HANDLE NO-UNDO.
   DEFINE VARIABLE v-chr-range             AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.
   DEFINE VARIABLE v-int-line              AS INTEGER    NO-UNDO INITIAL 1.
   DEFINE VARIABLE v-int-ultimalinha       AS INTEGER    NO-UNDO.
   DEFINE VARIABLE v-coluna-a AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(20)".
   DEFINE VARIABLE v-coluna-b AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(20)".

Comment: DEFINE VARIABLE v-coluna-c AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(20)".
   CREATE 'excel.application':U v-chr-excel-application.
   v-chr-excel-application:VISIBLE = TRUE.
   ASSIGN v-chr-work-book   = v-chr-excel-application:Workbooks:OPEN(c-nome-arquivo)
          v-chr-work-sheet  = v-chr-excel-application:Sheets:ITEM(1)
          v-int-ultimalinha = v-chr-excel-application:Activesheet:Usedrange:Rows:COUNT.

Comment: /*v-chr-work-sheet:Range("$A$1:$AC$568"):RemoveDuplicates:COLUMNS:Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, , 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29):HEADER:xlYes.*/
   v-chr-work-sheet:UsedRange:RemoveDuplicates("A:AC",1) /*("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, , 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29", YES)*/.
   /*Range(“A1:C8”).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes*/
   v-chr-excel-application:Workbooks:APPLICATION:QUIT.
   RELEASE OBJECT v-chr-excel-application NO-ERROR.

Comment: RELEASE OBJECT v-chr-work-sheet        NO-ERROR.
   RELEASE OBJECT v-chr-work-book         NO-ERROR.
END PROCEDURE.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax *should* be:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE columnsArray AS INTEGER EXTENT 2 NO-UNDO.  
      
columnsArray[1] = 1 .
columnsArray[2] = 2 .
      
v-chr-work-sheet:Range("A1:A5"):RemoveDuplicates(columnsArray, 1 /* XlYesNoGuess:xlYes */ ) .
```

For the array, you pass in an ABL array and the header constant needs to be replaced by a single integer value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlyesnoguess

However the code errors, but maybe this helps you get further.

Error occurred while accessing component property/method: RemoveDuplicates.
Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.

Error code: 0x80020009 test.p (5890)